# If $A$ is a positive definite bilinear form defined on a real vector space, does it satisfy the following condition?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a positive definite bilinear form defined on a real vector space, does $A$ satisfy $2A(u,u)^\frac 12 A(v,v)^\frac 12 \ge A(u,v) + A(v,u)$?

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, this is just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.  Are you assuming that $A$ is positive-definite, but not necessarily symmetric?

Comment: No $A$ is not necessarily symmetric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ 0 \leq A(u+tv,u+tv) = A(u,u) + t(A(u,v)+A(v,u))+t^2 A(v,v), $$
using the bilinearity. The inequality implies that the expression on the left has at most one real root, so the discriminant "$b^2-4ac$" must be nonpositive. Hence
$$ (A(u,v)+A(v,u))^2 \leq 4 A(u,u)A(v,v), $$
and taking the positive square root gives the result.

Comment: Oh got it! Thanks!!! This question has been bothering me for a long time

Comment: Yeah, it is a imitation of the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality!